# How can I increase height of a textbox without Multiline = "true" or incrementing font size?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I need to adjust height of the textbox so it is suitable for touchscreen.

I understand people recommend `Multiline = "true"` but if I do that, text inside of the box is justified with top which is not proper in my application.

I tried to adjust font size, but the size should be ridiculously huge to fit the height for my need.

Is there any other way to increase the height of textbox?

Comment: You could use padding, which will grow the textbox _and_ justify it 'normally', I think.

Comment: @david That wasn't properly thought through: we don't have `Padding` for TextBox in WinForms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
textBox1.AutoSize = false;
```

It won't show up in the intellisense, but it will work.

To have it work with the designer, you would have to make your own TextBox:

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox {
  public TextBoxEx() {
    this.AutoSize = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: @david The only other way is to take a borderless TextBox and place it inside a UserControl with the same BackColor, then handle the placement of the TextBox within the confines of the UserControl as it is resized.  Not ideal, you lose the TextBox borders with their visual styles.  WinForms is not good at this while WPF handles this better.

Comment: @LarsTech Making the textbox appear bigger doesn't seem to fit what the OP is looking for. He actually wants the textbox to be bigger, so it is easier to touch.

Comment: @McKay Aren't I addressing that?  The OP does not want MultiLine=True nor increment the font size.  What other choices are there in WinForms?

Comment: Yeah your suggestion seems to be the only solution. I really didn't expect UI for touchscreen to be so different from conventional Winform UI. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @LarsTech I was referring to the comment about the borderless text box. Making it appear larger wouldn't work, because if the touch experience hit the part that looked like text box, it wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: @Nyerguds Your comment actually makes no sense.  If a single line textbox wrapped, then it would have to be multiline.

Comment: @LarsTech Not really. My use case is a single line of text that should never contain line breaks, displayed in a rather narrow textbox. I would like it to wrap when it gets too long, and make use of a vertical scrollbar if it gets large. Sadly, the "MultiLine"  property always affects both the control _and_ its contents; once you set it to MultiLine, it'll allow line breaks.

Comment: @LarsTech In the end I just went for KeyPress and Textchanged listeners filtering out all line breaks. Took some creative fiddling to retain the text cursor position though.

Answer (score 1):

Trick steps:

1. Set the multi-line = true
2. No need to change the Font size.
3. change the Max-length . so that it should not enter the next line.

Comment: Mind that with this approach, you can still type or paste a line break in the bounds of the character limit.

Answer (score 0):

For what I wanted to do using a label instead with `BorderStyle=Fixed3D` and `AutoSize=False` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below solution to be a decent-enough compromise. It turns off the control's AutoSize property and increases the font size of its contents. Thus far, it seems to hold up well for various DPI contexts.

```
public class SingleLineTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        if (Font is Font font)
            using (font)
            {
                // Suppress the single-line textbox's fixed height
                AutoSize = false;
                // Increase size of textbox contents to compensate
                // for vertical shift
                Font = new Font(font.FontFamily, font.Size + 0.75F);
            }
    }
}
```

After this solution:

[image: After this solution]

Before this solution:

[image: Before this solution]